# How can I check if any of my boolean variable is false in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Can I ask if is this is the only way to check if a variable is false in VB.net?

here is my code

```
if a = true and b = true and c = true then
     msgbox("ok")
else if a= true and b = true and c = false then
     msgbox("c has errors")
else if a= true and b = false and c = true then
     msgbox("b has errors")
else if a= false and b = true and c = true then
     msgbox("a has errors")
end if
```

Comment: You need to ask the actual question you want an answer to.  Your code suggests that you want to determine whether one and only one of the variables is `False` and which one it is.  Is that the case?  If not, please describe EXACTLY what the case actually is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney well you got it right

Comment: By the way, what you are doing is not objectively wrong but it is more correct to use `If a And b And Not c Then` rather than `If a = True And b = True And c = False Then`.  It is also more appropriate to use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` over `And` and `Or` unless you specifically need short-circuiting, which is rare.

Comment: It still depends on the specifics because it seems unlikely that you would actually display a variable name to the user.  It's easy enough to determine whether a list of values contains exactly one that matches another value and it's easy enough to determine the index of that match, but getting the original variable name for that value is something else, but something else that it would be weird to need in the first place.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I just want to check if the code I created is the only code that can check if three Boolean variables has a false in it. That's it! I keep on using this as my code but it seems to me its kind of messy.

Comment: *"check if three Boolean variables has a false in it"*. If that's what you actually want then why did you say that I was correct earlier when I described something else? If you can't provide a coherent explanation of your problem then how are we supposed to know what we're providing a solution to?  Determining whether ANY of a set of flags is `False` is NOT the same thing as determining whether ONE of them is `FALSE`.  Your code also indicates that you want to know WHICH flag is `False`. Use your brain, consider what you want to do and then describe it ACCURATELY and CLEARLY.

Comment: Use of `= True` or `= False` for `Boolean` variables is typically unnecessary, you could simply do e.g. `If (Not a) And b And c Then ...`

Comment: create a truth table and then create a generalised formula. you will find a single line answer, probably along the lines of "Not(Not A or Not b or Not c)" (do your own truth table because I just made that answer up without checking).

Answer (score 4):

It's more for the code review section, but I give the answers anyway...

For my aesthetics it is ugly to write `If (a = True) Then` or `If (a = False) Then`, I would rather use `If (a) Then` and `If (Not a) Then`.

In your code, if a + b have errors, nothing happens, as this case is not handled. A Rolls-Royce implementation could look like this:

```
Public Class Application

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        '... get the results from 3 calls to other methods
        Dim a As Boolean = MethodA()
        Dim b As Boolean = MethodB()
        Dim c As Boolean = MethodC()
        Dim myErrors As String = GetErrorMessage(a, b, c)
        If (myErrors Is Nothing) Then
            MsgBox("ok")
        Else
            MsgBox(myErrors)
            Environment.Exit(-1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetErrorMessage(a As Boolean, b As Boolean, c As Boolean) As String
        If (a AndAlso b AndAlso c) Then Return Nothing
        Dim myList As New List(Of String)(3)
        If (Not a) Then myList.Add(NameOf(MethodA))
        If (Not b) Then myList.Add(NameOf(MethodB))
        If (Not c) Then myList.Add(NameOf(MethodC))
        Select Case myList.Count
            Case 1
                Return $"{myList(0)} has errors!"
            Case 2
                Return $"{myList(0)} and {myList(1)} have errors!"
            Case Else
                Return $"{String.Join(", ", myList.Take(myList.Count - 1))} and {myList(myList.Count - 1)} have errros!"
        End Select
    End Function

    Private Function MethodA() As Boolean
        'Does something
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function MethodB() As Boolean
        'Does something
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function MethodC() As Boolean
        'Does something
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

As a general recommendation, I would not return a boolean from the 3 calls but implement them as Sub instead and throw an exception if something goes wrong, that allows you to give more accurate feedback and also to handle the error higher up the call stack if you prefere. Here an example of such an implementation:

```
Public Class Application

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Dim myErrors As List(Of String) = Nothing
        Try
            MethodA()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If (myErrors Is Nothing) Then myErrors = New List(Of String)(3)
            myErrors.Add($"{NameOf(MethodA)}: {ex.Message}")
        End Try
        Try
            MethodB()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If (myErrors Is Nothing) Then myErrors = New List(Of String)(2)
            myErrors.Add($"{NameOf(MethodB)}: {ex.Message}")
        End Try
        Try
            MethodC()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If (myErrors Is Nothing) Then myErrors = New List(Of String)(1)
            myErrors.Add($"{NameOf(MethodC)}: {ex.Message}")
        End Try
        If (myErrors Is Nothing) Then
            MsgBox("OK")
        Else
            MsgBox($"The following errors occurred:{vbCrLf}{vbCrLf}{String.Join(vbCrLf, myErrors)}")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MethodA()
        'Does something
    End Sub

    Private Sub MethodB()
        'Does something
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MethodC()
        'Does something
        Throw New NotSupportedException()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I will solve it checking each one of the Boolean then storing the error if any.

```
Dim Report as String = ""

If a = false Then
    Report = Report & vbCrlf & "a has errors"
End If

If b = false Then
    Report = Report & vbCrlf & "b has errors"
End If

If c = false Then
    Report = Report & vbCrlf & "c has errors"
End If

If Report = "" Then
    Msgbox("OK")
Else
    Msgbox(Report)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to put the Booleans in an array. The loop through checking for the value = False. The index of the False values are added to lstIndexes.

```
    Dim lstIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim bools = {a, b, c}
    For i = 0 To bools.Length - 1
        If Not bools(i) Then
            lstIndexes.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I like Cristoph's answer, if the goal is to throw an error message and not proceed then could you not also just do this?

```
Public Sub DoSomething(a as Boolean, b as Boolean, c as Boolean)

    If Not a Then
        MsgBox("A has errors!") ' Or have a log message or throw an exception.
        Exit Sub                ' Or Return Nothing if it's a function
    End If

    If Not b Then
        MsgBox("B has errors!") ' Or have a log message or throw an exception.
        Exit Sub                ' Or Return Nothing if it's a function
    End If

    If Not c Then
        MsgBox("C has errors!") ' Or have a log message or throw an exception.
        Exit Sub                ' Or Return Nothing if it's a function
    End If

    DoNextThing()

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but if a and b have errors, only the message "A has errors!" is displayed because of the ```Exit Sub```.

Comment: Yes, this is more of a fix your first problem before proceeding sort of approach. This is rather common with file checks, the file has to exist before anything else can be done for example.

Comment: Little suggestion for simplicity and readability: `Report &= "a has errors" & vbCrlf`